# Updating Convert() Operation for MariaDB in SQL Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am updating some SQL queries as necessary now that we've moved to MariaDB rather than using SQL Anywhere. One line I need to change involves a `convert()` operation. The MariaDB syntax for `convert()` states that this takes two arguments, the value and the data type - and the data type should be second. So, that being the case, how would I update this line for MariaDB?

```
CONVERT(a.time_started, 100, CHAR) AS 'Waiting Since',
```

I tried wrapping the first two in brackets, like so:

```
CONVERT((a.time_started, 100), CHAR) AS 'Waiting Since',
```

... but that produced its own error about having one operand.

I'm more familiar with MongoDB than I am with SQL, so I'd also like to understand what the `100` in this line represents.

So what does that represent, and how should this be re-written to work with MariaDB?

Comment: What does `CONVERT(a.time_started, 100, CHAR)` do?

Comment: `CONVERT` is a SQL Server function, but the syntax in your snippet is pretty off.  Whence is the source of this `CONVERT` code?

Comment: I didn't write it. I inherited it from staff who wrote it a long time ago. So I'm not exactly sure what it is supposed to accomplish. That's partly why I asked about the `100`, and what its purpose might be here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is SAP SQL Anywhere

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, I am updating this from SQL Anywhere to work with MariaDB.

Comment: @Muirik The `100` is probably a format mask, telling SAP how to format the input date as text.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. So that being the case, how could I pass that information along in a MariaDB friendly format for the convert() operation? Or is the `100` superfluous in this case?

Comment: @Muirik how does the value of `a.time_started` look like ? and when you execute `SELECT CONVERT(a.time_started, 100, CHAR) AS 'Waiting Since' ...` in SQL Anywhere, what do you get ?

Comment: Btw, Syntax in official docs is different: http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/convert-function.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SAP documentation for CONVERT](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a898e08b84f21015969fa437e89860c8/16.1.3.0/en-US/a53f6efb84f21015af0e8594ce5cd68e.html), the format mask `100` corresponds to the following format mask:

```
mmm dd yyyy hh:nnAM (or PM)
```

For example:

```
 Sep  9 2019  2:24PM
```

We can try may using MariaDB's `DATE_FORMAT` as follows:

```
DATE_FORMAT(a.time_started, '%b %d %Y %r') AS `Waiting Since`
```